# SwiftUI - performance issue when adding GeometryReader inside a ScrollView

Tags: swiftui

I had created a list with 5000 cells and a text label showing its position on top.
Just find that the view looks laggy and the CPU is in full usage while I scroll the list.

I try comment the code of updating self.offset inside the GeometryReader block, everthing look smooth but I'm not able to show the position anymore.

Please, can somebody help?

Here's my sample codes.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            CustomTextView()
            
            VStack {
                ForEach(0..<5000, id: \.self) { i in
                    HStack {
                        Text("\(i)")
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.red)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CustomTextView: View {
    @State private var offset: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(self.offset)")
            .frame(height: 100.0)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(GeometryReader(content: { geo -> Color in
                Task { self.offset = geo.frame(in: .global).minY }
                return Color.gray
            }))
    }
}
```

a smooth scrolling is expected and the CPU usage should be normal.

Comment: Have you tried replacing ```VStack``` with ```LazyVStack```?

Comment: Hi @BenzyNeez, it works fine, but why? based on my understanding, the body of `ContentView` should not be called even I update the `offset` state property constantly.

Comment: I guess the heavy overhead is because the version with ```VStack``` is having to handle the display of 5000 rows. I added an answer now with a further suggestion too.

Comment: A little bit confused. If those 5000 rows are the root cause of heavy load, then why it looks smooth when I stop updating the `offset`. based on my understanding to SwiftUI, the update on @State `offset` only re-create `CustomTextView`, therefore, there should not perform any loading action on the list's body (aka the huge cells).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest two changes:

1. In `ContentView`, replace `VStack` with `LazyVStack`:

```swift
        ScrollView {
            CustomTextView()

            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(0..<5000, id: \.self) { i in
                     // as before
                }
            }
        }
```

2. In the body of `CustomTextView`, use an `.onChange` modifier instead of a background task to update the `offset` state variable:

```swift
            .background(
                GeometryReader { geo in
                    Color.gray
                        .onChange(of: geo.frame(in: .global).minY) { newOffset in
                            offset = newOffset
                        }
                }
            )
```

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion is really helpful. I try replacing `ScrollView` with `List`, it works fine too, because the cells inside the list is loaded lazily.

Comment: Is there another solution if non-lazy Stack is required? For some reasons, I have to keep the status of the cells.

Comment: I think the 5000 rows are the main cause of your performance issues and lazy loading is probably the best way to resolve it. If you find that performance is not bad when the scroll position is not tracked then maybe review why you need the exact position in the first place. Can you approximate it? Or use a ScrollViewProxy if the reason for having it is for positioning?

Comment: In fact, there is a cell showing a list of videos horizontally. Those videos can be paused or played, depend on its offset. The system may reset those videos if lazy Stack is applied in this case.

Comment: OK, so if you don't want the individual videos to be reset when they go out of view and are later brought back into view, maybe you need to hold the status in a separate object that can outlive the video frames? A container for all play status could be owned by the parent view and an object which encapsulates the status of an individual video could be passed to each player. This would allow a LazyVStack to be used again.